# "object not found" while connecting to mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have created my database "MUSIC" in phpmyadmin in xampp. I am trying to connect to this database using a php file which i have stored in the OML folder which in turn is present in the htdocs folder my code is:

```
$db_name="MUSIC";
$db_user="root";
$db_pwd="ash123";
$db_host="localhost";

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","ash123");
mysql_select_db("MUSIC");
echo "connection successful";
```

but when I go to localhost and type `localhost/connect.php`, I get this error:

```
Object not found!
the requested URL was not found on this server.if u entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.If you think this is a server error,please contact webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.3 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
```

I have searched but I have found a solution to this problem, please help!

Comment: Does the file exist? Are you sure the document root is set to the correct directory?

Comment: By default XAMPP uses port 8080, and the php file should be in the /htdocs folder. Try http://localhost:8080/connect.php

Comment: Did the error actually say "... if u entered the URL manually ..." ;)

Answer (score 1):

> i am trying to connect to this database using a php file which i have
>   stored **in the OML folder which in turn is present in the htdocs folder**

So, the URI would be `/OML/connect.php` instead of just `/connect.php`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this in the address bar: "localhost/OML/connect.php"

Answer (score 0):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","ash123","MUSIC");
```

Replace this code in database connection file . Remove the codes you shown .

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_connect()` is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php), and you improperly select the database.

Your code should be:

```
$db_name="MUSIC";
$db_user="root";
$db_pwd="ash123";
$db_host="localhost";

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_pwd, $db_name);
if (!$link->connect_error) {
  echo "connection successful";
} else {
  echo $link->connect_error
}
```

At that point the connection is established, and the DB is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this to connect to your data base

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "ash123", "MUSIC");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Warning ERROR while connection DataBase." .mysqli_connect_errno();
}
?>
```